# PlayGamesPlatform method "RequestServerSideAccess" return null and error "com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I'm trying to do server-side authorization of a user using the authorization key that the **PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RequestServerSideAccess** method should return, but I'm getting the error **com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:**

**How I set up the project configuration:**

**1.** I installed the plugin https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

**2.** I created a keystore in unity

**3.** I created a game in play.google.com/console

**4.** I created an OAuth 2.0 authorization with the Android type

**4.1.** I pasted "Package name" from my application settings in unity (Project Settings/Player/Identification/Package Name)

**4.2.** I generated the SHA-1 certificate like this:

**4.2.1.** I went to the console in the directory "C:\Program Files\Java\jre-1.8\bin" and used the command "keytool -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v" specifying the address of my keystore

**4.2.2.** Copied SHA-1 and pasted it where needed

**5.** In "Window/Google Play Games/Setup/Android setup" I set the Web App Client Id received after creating OAuth 2.0 authorization

**6.** In "Window/Google Play Games/Setup/Android setup" I pasted resources by copying them from the configuration page "Credentials" -> "Get resources"

**7.** In "Window/Google Play Games/Setup/Nearby Connections setup" I inserted the same package name as in 4.1

**8.** I made a build for Android by entering the password from my keystore

**9.** I launched a build on my Android, where authorization was successful, but the RequestServerSideAccess method returns null

**I've already tried everything:**

I deleted and created keystore with a new SHA-1 fingerprint

I used the fingerprint in "C:\Users\USERNAME.android\debug.keystore"

I deleted the game and recreated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was necessary to create OAuth 2.0 with type Web Application and paste client id to "Window/Google Play Games/Setup/Android setup"